# Making my own translator with using googletrans with python

Tags: python-3.x, google-translator-toolkit

I just prepare something but my code is not working I mean I get a white screen and buttons are not displaying on the page. I thought the problem could be with my computer I'm still using a pc with intel pentium 32 bit but also I could be wrong so my codes are below to post if you could help me I will appreciate that.

```
import tkinter as tk
from googletrans import Translator

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("My Translator")
win.geometry("200x100")


def translation():

word = entry.get()
translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.google.com'])
translation1 = translator.translate(word,dest='ru')
label1 = tk.Label(win,text=f"Translated in Russian : {translation1.text}",bg="yellow")
label1.grid(row=2,column=0)
label = tk.Label(win,text="Enter Word :")
label.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="W")

entry = tk.Entry(win)
entry.grid(row=1,column=0)

button = tk.Button(win,text="Translate",command=translation)
button.grid(row=1,column=2)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Formatting is crucial in python. The code in the question is not properly formatted, hence it does not make sense to talk about it. Please format the code properly.

Comment: sorry for that I m just new on stackoverflow and programing :) so now its fixed

Comment: @Melik improve your indentation

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for your comment do you mean you can fix this with indentation?

Comment: @Melik read https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation